# angularjs xeditable typeahead - update input field based on another input field value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question was asked about a year ago and normally I would not re-post a question but the answer that was given wasn't very clear and I am having the same issue. Original: [angularjs xeditable typeahead - update input field based on another input field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757547/angularjs-xeditable-typeahead-update-input-field-based-on-another-input-field/25757548#25757548)

I would normally use filter: {Property: data} but it threw an error in the browser...

```
   <a href="#" editable-select="ed.editTicket.Group" buttons="no" onbeforesave="ed.updateGroup($data)" onshow="ed.loadGroups()" e-ng-options="g as g.GroupName for g in ed.groups">{{ ed.group.GroupName || ed.editTicket.Group}}</a>
   <a href="#" editable-text="ed.editTicket.Technician" buttons="no" onbeforesave="ed.updateAgent($data)" e-typeahead="name as name.DisplayName for name in ed.agents | filter: $viewValue | {PrimaryGroupID: ed.group.GroupID} |  limitTo:8">{{ ed.agent.DisplayName || ed.editTicket.Technician}}</a>
```

Comment: Where is the second input field? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I just added the first x editable. onbeforesave is sending the value back to my controller and then I use that value throughout the controller and it is also being used in the second xeditable to filter the particular select.

Comment: Here is an example of what I am wanting to do with x editable typeahead: http://plnkr.co/edit/azK37CcLAaw1uTEjoirS